# jQuery: stop a <select> list from moving on keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML/jQuery like this:

```
<select id="userlist" name="userlist">
<option value=''></option>
<option value="ADJUDICATION">ADJUDICATION</option>
<option value="ADMINISTRATIVE">ADMINISTRATIVE LAW</option> # etc
</select>

$("#userlist").keypress(function(e) {
    windows_id += String.fromCharCode(e.which).toUpperCase();
    // Only do anything if we have more than 1 initial.
    if (windows_id.length > 1) {
    // do stuff here 
    }
});
```

As you can see, if the user types more than two characters in, I want to do something special.

My question is this: is there any way I can prevent the `<select>` list from moving after the user has typed just one character, and instead, hold it still until the user has typed two?

Thanks!

Comment: selecting the item that corresponds to the characters the user has typed in.

Comment: e.g. if you type 'AD', the list moves to ADMINISTRATIVE... at least in my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is browser behavior and cannot be overriden or stopped. If you want this specific behavior, you're going to need to implement a select like control using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stop a select from changing by returning false from a function bound to the `keydown` event (not `keypress`):

```
$('#userlist').keydown(function(e) {
    // ...stuff...
    return false;
});
```

Calling `e.stopPropagation()` from the event handler should serve just as well.

This works in Firefox 3.5.15 (on Fedora 12).  Other browsers may scroll the select on other key events, so you might have to catch those as well (with event handlers that simply return false).

Hope this helps!